# Skip module in step while debugging Haskell with GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am debugging a Haskell program with *GHCi*. I am using `:step` along with `:list`. There is a point where the program starts to pass repeatedly through the same functions within a `Parser.hs` module.

I was wondering if there is any way to resume the program with `:continue` till it exits this `Parser.hs` module, i.e.

- goes back to the next step where it entered it before

or

- calls function within another package.

Something like hidding this module from the debugger (I wouldn't mind to hide it for the complete execution). I couldn't find anything in the suggested commands with `:help` but I don't have a lot of experience with *GHCi* so I thought to try it here.

Cheers